# How to config Jenkins to build any branch whenever it committed to GitHub

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, githooks

I'd like to config jenkins that builds any branch whenever it committed to GitHub.
I did as below:

- At Source Code Management, I chose Git and Branch Specifier was **
- At Build Triggers, I chose `Build when a change is pushed to GitHub`

I tried to commit to branch (ex: fixBugAAA), but jenkins built all branches.
What did I do wrong? I just need to build only one branch I committed (ex: in this case fixBugAAA). How to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the "branches to build" field to limit the branches which can be built by the job?

Comment: I mean I don't need to limit the branches. I just need jenkins to build only one branch that I committed. (Ex: If I committed fixBugAAA branch, it will build fixBugAAA branch only, next time I committed fixBugBBB, it will build fixBugBBB branch only and so on...)